# 7-Zip doesn't ask me for a password for a ZIP file I encrypted while double-clicking it

Tags: windows, command-line, passwords, zip, 7-zip

I just tried to encrypt a folder with 7-Zip by a command line, choosing a password, but when double-clicking on the ZIP file, it shows me the files list without asking any password.

Is there a way to truly encrypt a folder from the command line?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The ZIP format doesn't allow for encrypting file lists. This means that file lists are viewable by anyone.

Only the contents of the files is encrypted, which means that no one can read the file without your password.

Due to this, 7-Zip only asks for your password before unzipping.

If you need a format that encrypts the file list, use `7Z` and make sure you check "Encrypt File Names".

For the more technical minded, the ZIP specification doesn't allow for encryption of the Central Directory.

Comment: The 7-Zip File Manager does not have the option to "Encrypt File Names". I guess you mean "7z.exe" and add things as parameters?

Answer (score 12):

You will be prompted for a password when you try to *extract* the files. To simply view the contents of the archive does not require a password.

If you would like to obfuscate the contents of the archive, compress the directory into an archive, and then compress *that* archive with a password.  Thus, you will have to extract the archive with a password, to pull out the archived (and obfuscated) contents.

Comment: Don't waste your CPU cycles on compression the second time round, if you can avoid it, though.

Comment: True enough. It's certainly easy enough to select Store for the compression mechanism on the second iteration. I have Fastest set as my default, and 7-Zip is ridiculously fast anyway. :)

Comment: This saved me the time!

Answer (score 4):

A generalized solution that works for all zip programs (WINzip, 7-Zip, MacZip, etc.) is to simply zip it twice making sure the second time (or both) have password protected encryption.

See: *[Filenames display without entering the password when an encrypted Zip file is opened](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/147)*

Answer (score 2):

I found your answer
in *[Do encrypted compression containers like ZIP and 7-Zip compress or encrypt first?](https://superuser.com/questions/260663/do-encrypted-compression-containers-like-zip-and-7-zip-compress-or-encrypt-first)*.

The command line switch to encrypt the headers (i.e. the file names) in 7-Zip is:

```
-mhe=on
```

e.g. 7z a -pPassword123 -mhe=on archive.7z file.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GNU Tar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm) to turn the directory into a single file, which you can then compress as a regular file with 7z.  Anyone viewing the archive will just see the tar file.

Comment: Hi Good suggestion

Comment: You don't need another tool; 7-Zip can also make a tar file. For instance, after choosing "Add to archive", chose "tar" for option "Archive format". There must be a similar option on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking will show you the files. Now try to extract one... as I recall, **that** is when you'll get the password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using **[Total Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander)** with the **[7-Zip Plugin](http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/7zip_plugin.html)**, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (or Files -> Pack...) to compress files or folders, click **Configure** and check the box **Encrypt File Headers and Names**.

*Other than that, Andrew Moore's answer is correct.*